# Figures in the alternatives

Tags: graphics, enumerate

I have to ask some questions with alternatives that are figures, some questions present vertical alternatives and others horizontal ones. I vaguely tried to do this,

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Imagen.png}
\end{figure}
\end{enumerate}
```

Even used subfigure but didn't get any good results. Some help?

I would like there to be 4 graphs as alternatives, my other problem is perhaps that all 4 fit on the sheet I am making. Just in case I attach my \geometry:

```
\geometry{paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm,left=2.2cm,right=2.2cm,%
    includeheadfoot,top=3.5cm,bottom=2cm,headheight=0pt}
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps just use `\includegraphics` in the `\item` without `\begin{figure}` etc., which creates a float that can move around.

Comment: Please tell us where the item number should be placed relative to the image: Along the top edge, along the bottom edge, in the middle, somewhere else?

Comment: I have no idea how the final result should look like. May be a sketch can help, along with reduced code, which compiles?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just attached an example.

Comment: Maybe the [`tasks`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks) package would be an option to print the images side by side (without using `figure`) with automatic numbering. [`enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) also provides inline lists (see section 4 of the manual).

Comment: For your second question about `geometry` please ask a new question an show a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `\includegraphics` without surrounding `\begin{figure}\end{figure}` (as suggested in comments) and do the numbering manually.

To top-align the images to the numbers you can use the `adjustbox` package that provides the `valign=t` key for including images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize % just to make the text smaller, not needed if you use \geometry
\begin{enumerate}
\item ¿Cuál(es) de los siguientes gráficos representa(n) una función en el intérvalo [-2,2]?\\
I) \includegraphics[width=2cm, valign=t]{example-image} 
II) \includegraphics[width=2cm, valign=t]{example-image-a} 
III) \includegraphics[width=2cm, valign=t]{example-image-b} 
\item Próximo ejercicio
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Maybe enlarge the line break a little:

```
\item ¿Cuál(es) [...] en el intérvalo [-2,2]?\\[2mm]
```

[image]